# Spring Boot bidirectional uniqueConstraints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I am developing a Backend for a Social Media App. When implementing the Logic for Following or Followers I got stuck.

Currently I have this defined in the UserModel Class but this I believe constraints it so User A can follow User B but User B cant follow User A back because then there would be a duplicate Combination of `follower_id` and `followed_id`.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_follows",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "follower_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "followed_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"follower_id", "followed_id"})
)
@JsonIgnore
private List<UserModel> following;
```

Comment: One way would be to create a separate table, with @ManyToOne relationship and add it there the combination `follower_id` `followed_id`. Then, you would need to add some extra business logic to validate the transactions. Or another option is to add a property in the `UserModel` class that marks it as `FOLLOWER`, or `FOLLOWING` and use `uniqueConstraints` on the three fields `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"follower_id", "followed_id", "status"}`